# Java split a string to get only alphanumeric (but not alpha or numeric)

Tags: java, regex, split, alphanumeric

currently I have the following code :

```
String test = "=(7+A15)-5";
if(test.matches(".*[A-z]+[0-9]+.*")){
    String spl[] = test.split("((?<=[A-z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4})|(?=[A-z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}))",3);
    System.out.println(spl[0] + "\n" + spl[1] +  "\n" +spl[2] );            
}
```

Which prints me :

```
=(7+
A1
5)-5
```

Except that I want :

```
=(7+
A15
)-5
```

But I have no idea why it only get one number when I ask {1,4}

Comment: `[A-z]` includes the characters `'[', '\\', ']', '^', '_',` and `'\`'`. There is no point in wrapping a string in `new String("foo")`.

Comment: What is the range of the Alphanumeric tokens (it will seem from your regex that you are looking from 1 to 4 {1,4} per Alpha and {1,4} per numeric. Will ABCD1234 be valid but ABCDEF12345 NOT?

Comment: Exactly, ABCD1234 is valid, while ABCDEF... isn't

Comment: @Naouk got a solution albeit is a weird one.....

Comment: Can you share it pls @gtgaxiola ? I've tried many things but can't find. I need to keep the delimiter and if it doesn't split correctly, nothing works

Comment: @Naouk check my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a delimiter such as

```
String delimiter = "[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}";
```

Then do both a `lookahead` and `lookbehind` in order to capture the delimiter as well as the tokens you want to split.

```
//Lookahead and lookbehind where %1 is the delimiter
String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
String regex = String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, delimiter);
```

Since it seems the capturing group splits the moment the regex is matched

Example: `A15` gets split into `A` `1` and `5`

You need to iterate over your tokens to concatenate those tokens that are in fact delimiters (using a different matcher)

```
String matcher = "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+";
String[] s = text.split(regex);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
String tmp = "";
for (String x : s) {
    if (x.matches(matcher)) {
        tmp += x;
    } else {
        if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        }
        result.add(x);
    }
}
if(!tmp.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(tmp);
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
public static List<String> splitWithDelimiter(String text, String delimiter) {
    String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
    String regex = String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, delimiter);
    String matcher = "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+";
    String[] s = text.split(regex);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String tmp = "";
    for (String x : s) {
        if (x.matches(matcher)) {
            tmp += x;
        } else {
            if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(tmp);
                tmp = "";
            }
            result.add(x);
        }
    }
    if(!tmp.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(tmp);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "=(7+A185)-5";
    String delimiter = "[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}";
    List<String> s = splitWithDelimiter(test, delimiter);
    for (String x : s) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
=(7+
A185
)-5
```